# Por que eu estou recebendo esse erro "OperationalError at /admin/core/comment"?

Tags: python, django

Quando eu tento acessar o campo Commnets na minha área do admin eu recebo esse erro. Por quê?

```
OperationalError at /admin/core/comment/

no such column: core_comment.content

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/core/comment/
Django Version:     3.1.2
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such column: core_comment.content

Exception Location:     /home/danilo/www/github/blog_application/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  /home/danilo/www/github/blog_application/.venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/danilo/www/github/blog_application',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/danilo/www/github/blog_application/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 28 Oct 2020 11:14:47 -0300
```

Minha model é essa:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published'))

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()

    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:post', args=[self.slug])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField()
    content = models.TextField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

e meu admin é esse

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'published', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'published', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'content')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'published'
    ordering = ('status', 'published')


@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'post', 'created', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'content')
    # search_fields = ('name', 'email')
```

Answer (score 0):

A app está tentando acessar a uma coluna da sua base de dados que não existe, este erro ocorre porque vc precisa executar as migrações depois de qualquer modificação no ficheiro models.py da sua app.

Executa estes comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Depois

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score -4):

## Execute estes comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

## Depois

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).